# Open WebView on Tab click or selection

Tags: android

**how can I open webView on Tab click or selection** 
On Tab **i==3** click event or select event. I want to open web view without opening tab how can I do this.
Here is my code there are 4 tabs on tab **i==3** click event I want WebView directly without opening tab.

```
 for (int i=0; i<tabs.length; i++){

        if(i==0)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_details, null);
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                     //.setCustomView(view)
                     .setCustomView(R.layout.tab_details)
                    .setTabListener(this)); 

        }
        else if(i==1){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_contact, null);
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                     //.setCustomView(view)
                     .setCustomView(R.layout.tab_contact)
                    .setTabListener(this)); 
        }
        else if(i==2){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_map, null);
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                     //.setCustomView(view)
                     .setCustomView(R.layout.tab_map)
                    .setTabListener(this)); 
        }
        else if(i==3){
             //here I want directly open WebView without opening tab                
        }
        else
        {
         actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                 .setText(tabs[i])
                .setIcon(MainActivity.this.getResources()
                 .getDrawable(ticons[i]))
                 .setTabListener(this));
        }
        }


    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {    
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

I hope I make all of you understand what I means

Comment: So, do you want to display webview in another activity ?

Comment: set mapview in the fragment

Comment: you are inflating one layout named #tab_buy_now ,at the time of 3rd tab selection . you can set your webview inside #popup dialog .

Comment: On tab click event open web view activity/fragment